# ConnectionRequest when back to the same form

Tags: codenameone

Here the NextPage form is opened when btn is clicked. Then after when I click the back button, the connection is again requested to open previous form (ie "Home"). It will take both time and data to do that. So what I want is that once the connection is done, i dont want to establish a connection again when back to the same form. How can i accomplish that?

```
@Override
protected void beforeHome(Form f) {
 btn.addActionListener((e)->{

  public void connectionForEmergencyListDetails(Form f, String categoryIdInt) {
    ConnectionRequest emergencyConnectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void postResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
           showForm('NextPage',null);
        }

    }
  }
 });
}
```

What I tried is that I stored the data in cache (storage) and it works in offline mode as well. But when there is a network connection, it establishes connection every time i go to the form. I don't want to establish the connection again when i go back to the same form since the data are already displayed and stored too in my case.

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't compile. You add a method into a lamba closure and you don't call the `addToQueue`.

I'm guessing that what you are looking for is [Storage.exists](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html#exists-java.lang.String-) which allows you to determine if you already have something in storage for the connection.

Comment: thanks but there is one more issue, if the data is updated, Storage.exists still gives true. Then the updated data will not be retrieved. What can be done to solve this condition?

Comment: What i want is that the datas are retrieved thru a connectionRequest in a form. Then thru a bottom or smth, app goes to next form. After that when i go back to the previous form, i dont want connectionRequest again. ie i want to run the request going forward but not when i go back to the same form again.

Comment: Updated in the server or in the storage? This might be interesting to you https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/services/CachedDataService.html